# No matching record found for external id ' ' in field 'Model'

Tags: odoo-15, access-rights

This is my error

```
Exception: Module loading helpdesk_module failed: file helpdesk_module\security/ir.model.access.csv could not be processed:
 No matching record found for external id ' model_helpdesk' in field 'Model'
No matching record found for external id ' model_tickets_tickets' in field 'Model'
Missing required value for the field 'Model' (model_id)
Missing required value for the field 'Model' (model_id)
```

This is my ir.model.access.csv:

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_helpdesk, access.helpdesk, model_helpdesk,,1,1,1,1
access_tickets_tickets, access.tickets_tickets, model_tickets_tickets,,1,1,1,1
```

This is my models:
helpdesk.py

```
from odoo import api, fields, models, _
class Helpdesk(models.Model):
    _name = "helpdesk"
    _description = "Helpdesk"

    tickets = fields.Char('My Tickets')
    performance = fields.Char('My Performance')
```

tickets_tickets.py

```
from odoo import api, fields, models, _
class TicketsTickets(models.Model):
    _name = "tickets.tickets"
    _description = "Tickets Tickets"

    name = fields.Char("Name", required=True)
    helpdesk_team = fields.Char("Helpdesk Team", required=True)
    assigned_to = fields.Char("Assigned to", required=True)
    customer = fields.Char("Customer", required=True)
    company = fields.Char("Company", required=True)
    next_activity = fields.Date("Next Activity", required=True)
    type = fields.Selection([('question', 'Question'),
                             ('issue', 'Issue'),
                             ('bug', 'Bug'),
                             ('documentation', 'Documentation')], default='issue')
```

i did follow odoo15 document, but still error

Comment: make sure the init files to include models ?

Comment: yes, i sure init files to include models, i can show src for you if you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i modified my ir.model.access.csv file to the following and it worked fine:

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_helpdesk,helpdesk,model_helpdesk,,1,1,1,1
access_tickets_tickets,tickets_tickets,model_tickets_tickets,,1,1,1,1
```

but i see tutorial of odoo [in here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxoEKE0cDQM&ab_channel=CybrosysTechnologies) it not working